# Plone 4 windows installation problem: bin-directory missing

Tags: installation, plone

Just installed Plone 4 on a WIN 7 64bit-PC in my own directory the third time now. The bin-directory is always missing. Any hints? Is there a way to create that dir with content manually?

Many thanks and greetings
plonestarter

Comment: You'll need to provide us with more information. Where do you expect the `bin` directory? What installer did you use?

Comment: I'm using the Windows installer. I was wondering why Plone didn't start, so I executed the command line via cmd. I got the error mesaage _"Can't open file 'MY_DIRECTORY\Plone\bin\plone-controll
er-script.py'_. So I looked after that file, but there was no \bin-directory at all.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell us how you are installing plone (unified installer or buildout).

If you are installing with zopeskel and buildout then you simply forgot to bootstrap your instance. In the root directory of your instance simply run this command (assuming your using python 2.6 as your default python) `python bootstrap.py`. I've never used the unified installer so I can't really help you there.

Comment: I'm using the Windows installer. I tried your hint, got the following messages:
`warning: no files found matching 'Makefile' under directory 'docs'`
`warning: no files found matching 'indexsidebar.html' under directory 'docs'`
`Creating directory 'D:\\ECM\\Plone\\bin'.`
`Creating directory 'D:\\ECM\\Plone\\parts'.`
`Creating directory 'D:\\ECM\\Plone\\develop-eggs'.`
`Generated script 'D:\\ECM\\Plone\\bin\\buildout'.`
In directory `bin' are now two files:
'buildout.exe' and 'buildout-script.py'

Comment: When I first started working with Plone I was on Windows, but have since switched to Mac/Linux so I can't really go any further to work on this for you. Do you plan on deploying on Windows?

Comment: Now you need to run bin/buildout.exe to make the magic happen.

Comment: Yep, but...
Error: Couldn't open D:\ECM\Plone\bin\buildout.cfg

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that this is the Windows installer in use.

You say that you're installing in your directory. Is there any chance that the full pathname for the directory has any spaces in it? If so, try again using a target directory for which the full pathname includes no spaces (or other characters that might plague the Windows command line).

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Windows installer. The full path name contains no spaces. I use same directory on a Windows XP-Netbook without any problems.